# Protractor element.click() fires the click event for the previous item in an unordered list

Tags: angular, jasmine, webdriver, protractor

I am using protractor to regression test an Angular2 application. When I access the element through by.id and execute a `click()` event to navigate to that section of the application, it actually clicks on the item above it. However, it does not behave like this for the first two navigation items in the unordered list.

`app-nav-smart-settings` and `app-nav-smart-resproperties` work fine...everything else clicks the item above it.

Here is the HTML:

```
    <ng-container role="leftPanel">

    <ul class="nav navigation navigation-main navigation-accordion">

        <li>
            <a (click)="changeComponent('settings')" id="app-nav-smart-settings" [ngClass]="activeComponent == 'settings' ? 'active' : ''">
                <i class="icon-gear text-blue" tooltip content="Settings" position="right"></i> <span>Settings</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a (click)="changeComponent('reservoirproperties')" id="app-nav-smart-resproperties" [ngClass]="activeComponent == 'reservoirproperties' ? 'active' : ''">
                <i class="icon-dice text-blue" tooltip content="Reservoir Properties" position="right"></i> <span>Reservoir Properties</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a (click)="changeComponent('relativepermeabilities')" id="app-smartnav-relpermeabilities" [ngClass]="activeComponent == 'relativepermeabilities' ? 'active' : ''">
                <i class="icon-list text-blue" tooltip content="Relative Permeabilities" position="right"></i> <span>Relative Permeabilities</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a (click)="changeComponent('wellcompletion')" id="app-nav-smart-wellcompletion" [ngClass]="activeComponent == 'wellcompletion' ? 'active' : ''">
                <i class="icon-hammer text-blue" tooltip content="Well and Completion" position="right"></i> <span>Well and Completion</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a (click)="changeComponent('previewgrid')" id="app-nav-smart-previewgrid" [ngClass]="activeComponent == 'previewgrid' ? 'active' : ''">
                <i class="icon-ladder text-blue" tooltip content="Preview Grid" position="right"></i> <span>Preview Grid</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a (click)="changeComponent('wellschedule')" id="app-nav-smart-wellschedule" [ngClass]="activeComponent == 'wellschedule' ? 'active' : ''">
                <i class="icon-calendar2 text-blue" tooltip content="Well Schedule" position="right" ></i> <span>Well Schedule</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a (click)="changeComponent('results')" id="app-nav-smart-results" [ngClass]="activeComponent == 'results' ? 'active' : ''">
                <i class="icon-airplane2 text-blue" tooltip content="Results" position="right" ></i> <span>Results</span>
            </a>
        </li>

    </ul>

</ng-container>
```

Here is the protractor calls:

```
element(by.id('app-smartnav-relpermeabilities')).click();
```

Comment: Inspect the elements of the DOM and verify their IDs. Try logging the values of these elements in the browser console.

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking the element that contains the text instead

```
element(by.id('app-smartnav-relpermeabilities')).element(by.css('[class="icon-list text-blue"]')).click();
```